# How to parse one html page and take out text using class name or id of a html tag?

Tags: html, web-crawler, jsoup, html-parsing, apache-tika

I want to parse one html page and take out text using class name or id of a html tag.

Apache tika or jsoup? Suggest me any tool name which have more control to manipulate and take out texts using specific tags, id or class names of a html page.

Comment: I'm not sure about `tika` but `Jsoup` definitely  will do what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you an example of the three use cases using `Jsoup`, please see the comments in code:

> - get div elements by class name
> - get all div elements by tag name
> - get element by id

```
String html = "...";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

// get div elements by class name 
Elements divs = doc.select("div.myclass");
for (Element div : divs) {
    // print containing text
    System.out.println(div.text());
}

// get all div elements by tag name
divs = doc.getElementsByTag("div");
for (Element div : divs) {
    // print containing text
    System.out.println(div.text());
}

// get element by id
String id = "...";
Element element = doc.getElementById(id);
System.out.println(element.text());
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.. will check and then mark this answer.. @flavio-donze